# GCloud AppEngine Java Hello world / Quick start example fails to deploy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am following the quickstart provided by Google for Java apps on GCloud:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart

The run phase does work (the app deploys locally), but running `mvn appengine:deploy` produces a failed build. Help?

The log:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T09:58:13+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\levallois\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core


[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'helloworld' with 1 classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.1.0:war (default-war) @ helloworld ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=126583, ConflictMarker.markTime=109098, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=98, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=87430, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=41054, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=38, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=1222121, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=89, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=41628131, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=1631141}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:3.1.0:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.3:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:3.1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:3.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.7.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.11:compile
[DEBUG]       org.iq80.snappy:snappy:jar:0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:runtime
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.24:compile
[DEBUG]    com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.9:compile
[DEBUG]       xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[DEBUG]       xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.24:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:3.1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-mapping:jar:3.0.0:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.1.0
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.1.0
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:3.1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:3.1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:3.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.7.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.11
[DEBUG]   Included: org.iq80.snappy:snappy:jar:0.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.24
[DEBUG]   Included: com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.9
[DEBUG]   Included: xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.24
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:3.1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-mapping:jar:3.0.0
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.1.0:war from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.1.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.1.0:war' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) archiveClasses = false
[DEBUG]   (s) attachClasses = false
[DEBUG]   (s) cacheFile = C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld\target\war\work\webapp-cache.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) classesClassifier = classes
[DEBUG]   (s) classesDirectory = C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) escapedBackslashesInFilePath = false
[DEBUG]   (f) filteringDeploymentDescriptors = false
[DEBUG]   (f) includeEmptyDirectories = false
[DEBUG]   (s) outputDirectory = C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld\target
[DEBUG]   (s) primaryArtifact = true
[DEBUG]   (s) project = MavenProject: com.example.appengine-j8:helloworld:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) recompressZippedFiles = true
[DEBUG]   (f) resourceEncoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@54acff7d
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) supportMultiLineFiltering = false
[DEBUG]   (s) useCache = false
[DEBUG]   (f) useDefaultDelimiters = true
[DEBUG]   (f) useJvmChmod = true
[DEBUG]   (s) warName = helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (s) warSourceDirectory = C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld\src\main\webapp
[DEBUG]   (s) warSourceIncludes = **
[DEBUG]   (s) webappDirectory = C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (s) workDirectory = C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld\target\war\work
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [helloworld] in [C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[DEBUG] properties used {maven-failsafe-plugin=2.20, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, env.PROMPT=$P$G, env.VS120COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\, java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre, classworlds.conf=C:\Users\levallois\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\..\bin\m2.conf, java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\endorsed, env.USERNAME=LEVALLOIS, maven-source-plugin=3.0.1, sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 1, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, env.COMPUTERNAME=PRT19148, env.=C:=C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld, maven-gpg-plugin=1.6, java.version=1.8.0_131, maven-war-plugin=3.0.0, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, env.USERPROFILE=C:\Users\levallois, user.name=LEVALLOIS, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, env.LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\levallois\AppData\Local, env.WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE=C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log, maven-release-plugin=2.5.3, env.COMMONPROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files, env.VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, user.timezone=Europe/Paris, user.script=, path.separator=;, env.MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS=appengine:deploy -X, env.PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel, file.encoding=Cp1252, sun.java.command=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher appengine:deploy -X, env.NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4, plexus-compiler-javac-errorprone=2.8.2, env.APPDATA=C:\Users\levallois\AppData\Roaming, env.WINDIR=C:\Windows, java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\LEVALL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\, user.language=fr, line.separator=
, env.COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files, failOnMissingWebXml=false, java.vm.info=mixed mode, maven-resources-plugin=3.0.2, sun.desktop=windows, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, project.reporting.outputEncoding=UTF-8, env.M2_HOME=C:\Users\levallois\apache-maven-3.5.2, env.PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.RB;.RBW, env.WDIR=C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud, netbeans.installation=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1, env.LOGONSERVER=\\HOMEDC02, env.PSMODULEPATH=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\PowerShell, maven-site-plugin=3.6, java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob, env.JAVACMD=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe, env.JVMCONFIG=\.mvn\jvm.config, env.PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public, env.USERDOMAIN=HOME, env.PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6, env.PROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86), env.=EXITCODE=00000001, os.name=Windows 7, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, env.TMP=C:\Users\LEVALL~1\AppData\Local\Temp, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, maven-checkstyle-plugin=2.17, maven-deploy-plugin=2.8.2, nexus-staging-maven-plugin=1.6.8, env.OS=Windows_NT, java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CloudFoundry;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;C:\Users\levallois\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\levallois\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\;C:\Users\levallois\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\levallois\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\levallois\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin;., env.PROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files, env.PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CloudFoundry;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;C:\Users\levallois\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\levallois\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\;C:\Users\levallois\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\levallois\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\levallois\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin, library.jansi.path=C:\Users\levallois\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\..\lib\jansi-native, java.class.version=52.0, maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud, versions-maven-plugin=2.3, env.HOMEDRIVE=C:, env.SYSTEMROOT=C:\Windows, env.COMSPEC=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe, maven-surefire-plugin=2.20, sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin, project.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8, env.SYSTEMDRIVE=C:, env.PROCESSOR_REVISION=4501, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment, user.variant=, env.PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files, java.vm.specification.version=1.8, env.PROGRAMDATA=C:\ProgramData, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit, env.MAVEN_HOME=C:\Users\levallois\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\.., sun.cpu.isalist=amd64, sun.stderr.encoding=cp850, env.MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR=C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud, maven-compiler-plugin=3.6.1, java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext, os.version=6.1, env.ERROR_CODE=0, user.home=C:\Users\levallois, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, maven-clean-plugin=3.0.0, env.USERDNSDOMAIN=HOME.EM-LYON.PRIV, env.JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131, user.dir=C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld, maven.conf=C:\Users\levallois\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\../conf, error_prone_core=2.0.19, env.COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files, maven-archetype-plugin=3.0.1, env.FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO, sun.cpu.endian=little, env.ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData, env.CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher, env.PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64, java.vm.version=25.131-b11, java.class.path=C:\Users\levallois\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar, org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug, env.HOMEPATH=\Users\levallois, env.EXEC_DIR=C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld, env.UATDATA=C:\Windows\CCM\UATData\D9F8C395-CAB8-491d-B8AC-179A1FE1BE77, os.arch=amd64, maven.build.version=Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T09:58:13+02:00), maven-jar-plugin=3.0.2, maven-install-plugin=2.5.2, env.SESSIONNAME=Console, env.WINDOWS_TRACING_FLAGS=3, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, file.separator=\, maven-assembly-plugin=3.0.0, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_131-b11, sun.boot.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\classes, maven.version=3.5.2, env.TEMP=C:\Users\LEVALL~1\AppData\Local\Temp, env.VS110COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\, user.country=FR, jacoco-maven-plugin=0.7.9, maven.home=C:\Users\levallois\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\.., maven.compiler.target=1.8, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, env.CLASSWORLDS_JAR="C:\Users\levallois\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar", maven.compiler.source=1.8, java.specification.version=1.8, sun.arch.data.model=64, argLine="-javaagent:C:\\Users\\levallois\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.9\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\levallois\\Google Drive\\open\\getting-started-java-google-cloud\\appengine-standard-java8\\helloworld\\target\\jacoco.exec"}
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld\src\main\webapp]
[DEBUG] isFilteringDeploymentDescriptors: [false]
[DEBUG]  + index.jsp has been copied.
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml has been copied.
[DEBUG] Dump of the current build pathSet content -->
[DEBUG] index.jsp
[DEBUG] WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
[DEBUG] -- end of dump --
[DEBUG] Processing: appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.60.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.60.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [63 msecs]
[DEBUG] Excluding [] from the generated webapp archive.
[DEBUG] Including [**] in the generated webapp archive.
[DEBUG] Build won't fail if web.xml file is missing.
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\levallois\Google Drive\open\getting-started-java-google-cloud\appengine-standard-java8\helloworld\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/
[DEBUG] adding entry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/
[DEBUG] adding directory WEB-INF/classes/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an open report on the Cloud SDK public issue tracker that might be the same problem: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72808542

You could try running:

```
$ gcloud components update --version 186.0.0
```

That way you get an older version that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Yes I ended up doing this. That was a real pain but solved the issue.